# How can I set product price per taxonomy term on Ubercart?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, ubercart

I need price per taxonomy terms for products. Here is what I need precisely. So when I add products 'X', 'Y', 'Z' to Ubercart I sets them taxonomy term 'Offer' which has price 10$. These products then have same prices. So when customer add any of these products from this term to cart it will get same price for every product.

Thanks for help M.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automate this, use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module. another option is ubercart core options.